# stopped when execute delete and update

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am doing an operation to first delete a record then insert in to the same table like this:

```
String delete = "DELETE FROM t WHERE t.id = id"
String insert = "INSERT INTO t VALUES (id, value1, value2)"

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate(delete);
s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate(insert);
```

then my application just blocked there after executing the insert statement. no response at all.

does any one know whats going on?

the db is oracle 11g.

Comment: "then my application just blocked there". Umm, care to point out at which line has the app blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. the AUTOCOMMIT flag is set to OFF.

Comment: How does that affect anything?  Unless you are executing the two statements in separate sessions which would seem highly unlikely given the code sample you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The code below does not need the WHERE clause since you will delete all recorde from t where the id is equal to the id.  Was that the intent or did you want to delete a specific id?

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE t.id = id
```

Answer (score 1):

do s.close() after the deletion and insertion

Answer (score 1):

you are misusing the sql statements

```
String delete = "DELETE FROM t WHERE t.id = ?"
String insert = "INSERT INTO t VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

PreparedStatement s = null;
try{
    s = conn.prepareStatement(delete);
    s.setNString(1,id);
    s.executeUpdate();
}finally{if(s!=null)s.close();s = null;}
try{
    s = conn.prepareStatement(insert );
    s.setNString(1,id);
    s.setNString(2,value1);
    s.setNString(2,value2);
    s.executeUpdate();
}finally{if(s!=null)s.close();s = null;}
```

in your code you didn't pass anything from your local vars and the sql server didn't know where to get the values of id, value1 and value2

Answer (score 1):

s.executeUpdate(delete); 
are you sure that you didn't got some SQLException here, because this "DELETE FROM t WHERE t.id = id" seems as invalid statement

Answer (score 0):

If the database halts during heavy DML it may be due to the archive destination being full. Move archives to backup and the database will continue.